# Searching CSV file and if it's not in the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, search

I have a CSV file filled with ticket information. I created a small script to input ticket numbers separated by spaces into a list which searches the CSV file for each ticket in the list, and if it finds the ticket, it outputs info on that row.

My problem is if I search for a ticket not in the CSV file, it just skips past it and moves on, but I would like it to tell me that that ticket is not in the file. From what I can tell, it's searching the CSV file by row or line. If I try an `else` statement, it will start printing out every line in the CSV file, if that ticket's not in the row.

I need to be able to input multiple ticket numbers and have python search each one individually. If it finds the ticket in column 1, then print information from that row and if it doesn't find the ticket in any rows column 1, then print out that ticket followed by "is not in the file".

```
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('Path To CSV file', "rb"), delimiter=",")
newticket = raw_input('Enter Ticket Numbers:').split()

for line in file:
    for tickets in newticket:
        if tickets == line[1]:
            print(tickets, line[36], line[37])
```

Comment: If your CSV's of a manageable size, I'd go with PM 2Ring's solution, it's more efficient than yours and is a very common method for doing this sort of thing in Python. If your file is too large to fit in memory, I'd look into databases. But that's outside the scope of this question, and unless your csv is gigabytes in size, should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSV file isn't enormous, I suggest reading the whole thing, extracting the data you want into a dictionary, with the ticket number as the key. Searching a dict is very fast.

I've modified your file opening code to use the `with` statement, which fails gracefully if there's a problem reading the file. BTW, there's no need to specify the comma as the CSV delimiter, since that the default delimiter.

```
import csv

with open('Path To CSV file', "rb") as f:
    data = {line[1]: (line[36], line[37]) for line in csv.reader(f)}

newtickets = raw_input('Enter Ticket Numbers:').split()

for ticket in newtickets:
    line = data.get(ticket)
    if line:
        print(ticket, line)
    else:
        print(ticket, "not found")
```

The `dict.get` method returns `None` if the key isn't in the dict, although you can specify another default return value if you want. So we could re-write that part like this:

```
for ticket in newtickets:
    line = data.get(ticket, "not found")
    print(ticket, line)
```

Alternatively, we could use the `in` operator:

```
for ticket in newtickets:
    if ticket in data:
        print(ticket, data[ticket])
    else:
        print(ticket, "not found")
```

All 3 versions have roughly the same efficiency, choose whichever you feel is the most readable.

Comment: I agree, though where you used `if line`, I would use `if line is not None` as if the value in the dictionary is falsey, it will fail the check even though the value was found. I think it's fair to make the assumption that the value in the dictionary's not `None` (if it is you'll probably want to just access the value and catch any exceptions), but it could very well be Falsey in many situations (e.g. having value `0`).

Comment: @SandeepDcunha You had me worried there for a moment. :) But the values in the dict are all 2-tuples, so it's impossible for them to be falsey. The only falsey tuple is the empty tuple `()`.

Comment: True, though since it's a number it would be very sensible to cast it to an int in which case it could very well have value 0. Also, if someone wants to adapt this code for another situation, they could run into this issue. When comparing for `None` and not general truthiness, it's best to do the explicit comparison `is not None`. I agree that your code would work perfectly fine in this scenario, but this is a possible pitfall it could encounter with slight adaptions to the code by OP or anyone else using it.

Comment: @SandeepDcunha But we aren't looking at the ticket number (which could very well be an alphanumeric "number"), we're looking at the tuple of `(line[36], line[37])` from the CSV file. However, I will agree that in many cases it _is_ better to use `if x is not None:` rather than simply `if x:`

Comment: Yes, in this case you definitely should not run into problems. I just wanted to point out that if you were only accessing one value, for example, you could quite possibly run into this problem. So, just to be safe against this problem with any future modifications of this code for slightly altered purposes, I felt that the comparison against `None` should be explicit.

Comment: @SandeepDcunha Personally, I'd probably use the `line = data.get(ticket, "not found")` version. It's the most compact, and that way the `None` issue doesn't arise.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you!!